# How to change owner of a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change owner of a file. I am currently logged as user1 and trying to set ownership to user2. I need to run chown as sudo(root) because the parent directory's permissions does not allow user1 to change ownership.

When I run the following code I get an error:

```
>>> getpass.getuser() #current user
'user1'

>>> os.chown("/me.txt", uid, gid)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/me.txt'
```

where uid and gid are for user2.

Comment: Are you running the script with an user that actually has permissions to execute that change ?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "change owner of a file as `root`". You're logged in as `user1`, so you are.. not `root`.

Comment: @OddNorg No, as user1 which does not have permissions.

Comment: Go back to the `os` package documentation for general usage.  You need to execute `os.system`(sudo chown ...)`.  You're focused on the `chown` part, when the primary command you need is `sudo`.

Comment: _No, as user1 which does not have permissions._ What is your question, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo` if user1 has permission to run `sudo chown`. It may ask for a password:

```
import os
os.system("sudo chown user2 /me.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way to accomplish this (i.e. not just using Python to run a shell command) would be to use [os.chown()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chown). For example, to pythonically change data.json ownership from root user to the current user running the script:

```
import os
from pwd import getpwnam


file = "data.json"
if path.owner() == 'root';
  user = os.getlogin()
  uid = getpwnam(user).pw_uid
  gid = getpwnam(user).pw_gid
  os.chown(path,uid,gid) # now `chown` the file to the current user
```